# Compare Products link or button does not work in Magento 1.9.3.2

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, magento-1.9

I have added a product comparison link but it doesn't work. This is in `Magento 1.9.3.2`

My issues are almost identical to this post, with the exception that clearing the index did not work.

Is there anything else I can try?

Here are the issues:

When I click "Add to Compare" on a product, a message stating that `such-and-such product successfully added to compare list` appears. However the compare products sidebar shows "You have no items to compare. But it's not working any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your Magento DB does not have `report_compared_product_index` table.

Import the following SQL to create this table structure in your DB.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `report_compared_product_index` (
  `index_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Index Id',
  `visitor_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Visitor Id',
  `customer_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Customer Id',
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Product Id',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store Id',
  `added_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Added At'
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Reports Compared Product Index Table' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `report_compared_product_index`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`index_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_REPORT_COMPARED_PRODUCT_INDEX_VISITOR_ID_PRODUCT_ID` (`visitor_id`,`product_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_REPORT_COMPARED_PRODUCT_INDEX_CUSTOMER_ID_PRODUCT_ID` (`customer_id`,`product_id`),
  ADD KEY `IDX_REPORT_COMPARED_PRODUCT_INDEX_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
  ADD KEY `IDX_REPORT_COMPARED_PRODUCT_INDEX_ADDED_AT` (`added_at`),
  ADD KEY `IDX_REPORT_COMPARED_PRODUCT_INDEX_PRODUCT_ID` (`product_id`);
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can test this:

Under **System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Validation Settings**

Set to **"NO"** the following:

```
<ul>
<li>
Validate REMOTE_ADDR 
</li>
<li>
Validate HTTP_VIA 
</li>
<li>
Validate HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR
</li>
</ul>
```